# How to add user to group using Telethon (Telegram python library) InviteToChannelRequest

Tags: python, telethon

I'm using the Telethon python library for Telegram and am currently trying to add users to my group using the following: https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/examples/chats-and-channels.html#adding-someone-else-to-such-chat-or-channel

However, I run into a problem with the InviteToChannelRequest function whose signature is the following:

```
channels.inviteToChannel#199f3a6c channel:InputChannel users:Vector<InputUser> = Updates
```

As you can see, the channel should be of type InputChannel however when I try to create an InputChannel to pass into the function using it's constructor, which is the following:

```
inputChannel#afeb712e channel_id:int access_hash:long = InputChannel
```

I do not have the group's access_hash so I'm unable to create a InputChannel to pass into the InviteToChannelRequest function.

So how exactly do I either get the access_hash of the group I want to add users to or how do I use the InviteToChannelRequest function?

If I try to create an InputChannel without the access_hash, this is the error I get:
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the group I had created was set to private so I went on the telegram app and set it to public and  after I did that, I ran this snippet:

```
result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
             offset_date=last_date,
             offset_id=0,
             offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
             limit=chunk_size,
             hash = 0
))
```

Which listed the details of the channel I wanted along with it's access_hash